# Identify highest CPU or memory consuming processes

Tags: memory, cpu, perfmon

I know that one of my Windows processes is having a very high memory and/or CPU consumption every once in a while but rather for a short time only (e.g. 10 minutes). Whenever I check the PC everything seems smooth though... How can I figure out which process is the villain? The solution which came to my mind is `perfmon` but I could imagine that the process of interest doesn't even run at the time I setup `perfmon`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ProcDump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) from Sysinternals to create a minidump when CPU or Memory thresholds are crossed.

Comment: Can I use ProcDump with just some thresholds? I believe I would have to specify the process... something I don't want to (otherwise I could use the perfmon solution). Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to monitor the CPU usage per task, open Task Manager and click more detail then click the CPU column and it will sort high to low usage, or low to high depending on where it was at.
Process Explorer in Sysinternals will give you a lot more detail if you need it.

Comment: As mentioned it didn't happen so far when I was in front of the PC. I used exactly this method to check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try the ways in the following article, some technical master give different ways, including perfmon, ProcDump and other ways. Hope it helps.

[Tracking CPU and Memory usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process)